# Camera Plugin is not working on Cordova 3.4.0 project

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I am already done my project with phonegap 2.2.0. Now,I am want update my project 2.2.0 to 3.4.0.So,I create a new project using cordova 3.4.0. I am add two platforms for this project(ios, android).I copied html,css and javascript files from my previous project.I have camera option in three pages.So, i installed cordova camera plugin using following comments **cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera** But, camera option was only working on one page.That time also i had following error in X-code console **['Camera'] took '37.391357' ms. Plugin should use a background thread**.

Please guide me....

The following codes are i am using

```
(function($) {
    var Core = window.Core || Core || {};
    Core.upload = {
        init: function (){
            Core.upload.bindEvents();
        },
        bindEvents: function() {  
        $('#upload_photo').bind('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            Core.upload.photo.get(navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY);
            return false;
        });
        $('#upload_camera').bind('click',function(){
            Core.upload.photo.capture();
            return false;
        });
        },
        photo: {
            get: function(source) {
                navigator.camera.getPicture(Core.upload.photo.onSuccess, Core.upload.photo.onFail,{
                quality: 50,
                sourceType: source,
                });
            },
            capture: function capturePhoto() {
                navigator.camera.getPicture(Core.upload.photo.onSuccess, Core.upload.photo.onFail, { quality: 50 });
            },
            onSuccess: function(imageData) {
            appendImage(imageData);             
            },
            onFail: function(message) {
                navigator.notification.alert(message);
            }
        }
    };
    $(Core.upload.init);
    window.Core = Core;
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you provide some code where you are calling your camera functionality?

Comment: @Arunkumar1775 I am facing the same problem, how did you fix this issue...

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
});

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Don't forget to update the new library and include in your build

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with Camera Plugin and i have used 
[mp-cordova-plugin-camera](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mp-cordova-plugin-camera)